# Pull Request Notifier for Bitbucket with jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, pull-request, bitbucket-server

With reference to this question : [Trigger jenkins build on stash pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937828/trigger-jenkins-build-on-stash-pull-request)

I tried applying Christian Galsterer's solution

You may have a look at https://christiangalsterer.wordpress.com/2015/04/23/continuous-integration-for-pull-requests-with-jenkins-and-stash/ where I describe the detailed steps how to setup Jenkins and Stash to trigger automatically the correct Jenkins build(s) when a pull request is created or updated.

It uses the Jenkins Git Plugin and the Pull Request Notifier for Stash add-on and selects the correct build using the notification feature of the Jenkins Git Plugin.

Everything works fine other than getting values of

```
PULL_REQUEST_URL=${PULL_REQUEST_URL}
PULL_REQUEST_ID=${PULL_REQUEST_ID}
```

It says "PR #null" in build description under jenkins and same in stash

```
"pullstash #19 A moment ago
<a href='null'>PR #null</a>"
```

Can someone please suggest what is missed here?

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the string parameters `PULL_REQUEST_URL` and `PULL_REQUEST_ID` in your Jenkins job.

Answer (score 0):

As per Christian's comment on that blog post:

> Starting with the Git Plugin 2.5 parameters send via the notification
>   are not automatically passed as parameters to the job for security
>   reasons.
>
> In order to allow again to pass the parameter to the job an additional
>   environment parameter needs to be set containing the name of the
>   parameters to pass.
>
> More details can be found at
>   https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/commit/cb778dd7ee1c7a3f820ac1021be89e60d56ac057.